What is the point of map_batches expression in polars?
I am reading about map_batches from the official documentation from
here:
Even though the example description says that the following sample code should return different results for map_elements and map_batches, I am getting identical results
out = df.group_by("keys", maintain_order=True).agg(
    pl.col("values").map_batches(lambda s: s.shift()).alias("shift_map_batches"),
    pl.col("values").shift().alias("shift_expression"),
)
print(out)
output:
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ keys ┆ shift_map_batches ┆ shift_expression │
│ ---  ┆ ---               ┆ ---              │
│ str  ┆ list[i64]         ┆ list[i64]        │
╞══════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ a    ┆ [null, 10]        ┆ [null, 10]       │
│ b    ┆ [null]            ┆ [null]           │
└──────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┘

You can see the two columns that are supposed to represent the results from the two approaches are identical
So, there doesn't seem to be any difference even though the documentation says that the two results should be different. Secondly, in a non-groupby scenario, we are passing the entire series to map_batches and elementwise to map_elements, so, here as well it would appear that we could have passed the series through the function and gotten the job done.
Taking the documentations example only:
counter = 0


def add_counter(val: int) -> int:
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return counter + val


out1 = df.select(
    pl.col("values").map_batches(add_counter).alias("solution_map_elements")
)

counter = 0
out2 = df.select(
    add_counter(pl.col("values"))
)
print(out1, out2)

So, I don't see a usecase for map_batches. I am trying to understand where we might use map_batches?

Docs need updating.
map_batches used to behave differently, that example needs amending.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14699#issuecomment-1969240018

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14521



Use case #1 - Performance
Another mention from the documentation:

"A reasonable use case for map functions is transforming the values represented by an expression using a third-party library."

If we use map_elements as a base case, we call Python's .swapcase() on every "Row".
df = pl.select(text = pl.repeat(pl.lit("áéíóúüñ" * 1000), n=100_000))

df.with_columns(out = pl.col("text").map_elements(lambda text: 
    text.swapcase(),
    return_dtype = pl.String
))

Elapsed time: 11.93447 seconds

Essentially, with map_elements we are doing the equivalent of:
for row in df[col]: 
    function(row)

PyArrow has a utf8_swapcase() compute function, which is another way to perform this task.
With map_batches the entire "Column" is passed and utf8_swapcase is called "once".
import pyarrow.compute

df.with_columns(out = pl.col("text").map_batches(lambda text: 
    pl.Series(pyarrow.compute.utf8_swapcase(text.to_arrow()))
))

Elapsed time: 4.05791 seconds

So in the case of where you have a 3rd-party function that accepts a "Column" you would use map_batches instead.

Use case #2 - Accessing the DataFrame API inside expressions
When Expr.replace() was originally introduced, it was implemented in Python and used .map_batches
An over-simplified example:
def my_custom_function(col, mapping, default=None):
    df = pl.LazyFrame({
        "old": mapping.keys(),
        "new": mapping.values()
    })
   
    select_expr = pl.col("new")
    if default is not None:
        select_expr = select_expr.fill_null(default)
        
    return (
        col.to_frame("old")
           .lazy()
           .join(df, on="old", how="left")
           .select(select_expr)
           .collect()
           .to_series()
    )

We call Series.to_frame() inside our function to get a DataFrame.
This gives us access to DataFrame methods e.g. .join() which is used map the old -> values.
lf = pl.LazyFrame({
   "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
   "b": [5, 6, 7, 8]
})

lf.with_columns(
   c = pl.col("a").map_batches(lambda col: 
      my_custom_function(
         col, 
         mapping = {2: "TWO", 4: "FOUR"}, 
         default = "FOUR O FOUR"
      )
   )
).collect()

shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c           │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str         │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ FOUR O FOUR │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ TWO         │
│ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ FOUR O FOUR │
│ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ FOUR        │
└─────┴─────┴─────────────┘

It's probably not something an "end user" would be using too much.

I see. I cannot replicate map_batches by just wrapping the pl.all() in my UDF because in that case expressions are sent to the UDF and not the actual data (pandas muscle memory). map_batches and map_elements make it possible not to be stuck with the expressions. I have a follow-up question: 1. The documentation suggests not using map_batches in the groupby context but, it seems the counterintuitive behaviour they demonstrated is now corrected. Now, shall we still not use map_batches with groupby and is there any difference now between map_elements and map_batches in the groupby context?

It is a bit confusing as it stands. Originally, map_batches silently ignored groupby context (this was by design) - Since the change, they essentially behave the same in a groupby context. There are a few different open issues on the tracker with regards to improving things.
